# PHP warning $post->ID is null

Tags: php, pages, errors

I've been having some difficulty with the following error, and my PHP skills are pretty non-existent. Whenever I try to create a new page, I get the following error: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in ... functions.php on line 1266 (also lines 1268 and 1271). This error maps to the use of `$post->ID`.

```
function autoset_featured() {
      global $post;
      $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail(**$post->ID**);
    if (!$already_has_thumb)  {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=**$post->ID**&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
        if ($attached_image) {
            foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
            set_post_thumbnail(**$post->ID**, $attachment_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, when adding a new "page," an error appears, until a featured image has been selected. But when the page is published, the image doesn't show. And when I adjust Page.php to display the image when published, the error still shows.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point to resolve this error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

NOTE: Here is my page.php code. I wasn't able to find where page.php was calling the function...

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template for displaying all pages
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Heidelbrew
 * @since Heidelbrew 1.0
 *
**/
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the code for content-page.php that page.php references

```
<?php
/**
 * Template used for displaying page content in page.php
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Heidelbrew
 * @since Heidelbrew 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'heidelbrew' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'heidelbrew' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Comment: you've assumed that `$post` refers to the current post, but what happens if there is no current post? E.g. if you click to add a brand new post, the post hasn't been created yet, so `$post` can't have an `ID`. What are you trying to do that requires this though? Even if you fix this issue this isn't the best solution, if your goal is to always ensure that if no featured image is set that it uses the featured image of a child post, then there are better ways to do that that do not involve this filter. Ask about your original problem, then instead present your code as an attempt to solve it

Comment: Ah! You're right! The moment I save, even without an image, then the errors go away. Cause the ID is created upon saving/publishing! Genius!